# Is there a program for theory of incompleteness in NP?

Tags: computational-complexity, proof-complexity

Motivated by Suresh's post, [Techniques for showing that problem is in hardness limbo](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/techniques-for-showing-that-problem-is-in-hardness-limbo/20891), it seems that there might be an underlying theory that explains why some of these problems can **not** be complete for $NP$.

For instance, the theory should explain why problems with polynomially bounded solutions (FewP) can not be complete. Also, it should explain why problems solvable by bounded nondeterminism (log-clique) can not be complete.

> Is there a research program that tries to link the apparent incompleteness of at least two candidate problems in Suresh's post? What are the obstacles to such program?

**EDIT** I am also interested in published research studying the connection between incomplete sets for $NP$ and finite versions of Godel's 2nd incompleteness theorem in the context of proof complexity.

Posted on [TCS SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31230/is-there-a-program-for-theory-of-incompleteness-in-np).

**EDIT 2**:

Some of the results in Suresh's post can be interpreted as (conjectured) necessary conditions for the $NP$-completeness of a given problem $B$:

1- Problem *B* must be exponentially dense.

2- Problem *B* can have exponential number of solutions.

3- Problem *B* must require linear nondeterministic bits to solve.

Comment: If $A$ is an incomplete set in $NP$ then the complement of $A$ is incomplete in $coNP$.

Comment: Clearly one can only hope for results conditional on complexity-theoretic assumptions, because any result of this type implies $P \neq NP$. In fact one might have to assume something significantly stronger than $P\neq NP$.

Comment: @WillSawin What is the strongest known complexity theoretic assumption?